# WebGL Three.js duplicate content

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a Website with WebGL content. For this I have a div-element for showing the WebGL.

Now I am trying to get this content in multiple divs on the same page. The content should be exactly the same. If it is possible the animation should be shown on all divs.

I have tried to create a second renderer and tried to add this to the second div but this seems not to work.

How can I get the same WebGL content in multiple divs on the same page?

This is my code for creating the WebGL content. renderer1 was my try to append to the second div but this didnt work.

```
<div id="WebGLCanvas"/>
        <script>
        var scene;
        var camera;
        var controls;
        var geometryArray;

        initializeScene();

        animateScene();

        function initializeScene(){
            if(!Detector.webgl){
                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                return;
            }

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
            renderer.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 1);
            renderer1 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
            renderer1.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 1);

            canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
            canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;

            renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

            renderer1.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

            document.getElementById("WebGLCanvas").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 1, 100);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 6);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            scene.add(camera);

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            axisSystem = new AxisSystem(camera, controls);

            geometryArray = new Object();
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            for(var i = 0; i < jsonFileNames.length; i++){
                var layerName = jsonFileNames[i].split("/")[2].split(".")[0];
                loader.load(jsonFileNames[i], function(geometry, layerName){
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors}));
                    mesh.scale.set(0.003, 0.003, 0.003);
                    mesh.doubleSided = true;
                    scene.add(mesh);
                    geometryArray[layerName] = mesh;
                }, layerName);
            }

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
            directionalLight.position = camera.position;
            scene.add(directionalLight);
        }

        function animateScene(){
            controls.update();
            axisSystem.animate();
            requestAnimationFrame(animateScene);
            renderScene();
        }

        function renderScene(){
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            axisSystem.render();
        }


    </script>
```

EDIT:
I have tried to add the renderer to a second div element but the scene than only appears on the last added div element and not on both.
This is the code I have tried. A simple example of what I am trying is that I want a left div element and a right div element. On both I want the same content. That means if I move the 3D object on my left element it should also move on the right element.

```
container = document.getElementById("webglcanvas");
container2 = document.getElementById("webglcanvas2");
containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
containerHeight = container.clientHeight;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, alpha:true});
renderer.setSize(containerWidth, containerHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
container2.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, take a look at this example. You just have to set the same camera not four different:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Viewports-Quad.html

Did you need something more?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have looked at the example but I don´t think that this is what I am trying to do as in the example everything is in one canvas element. I want to have 2 different div elements that are on different position on my page with exactly the same animation. For example I want to have a big animation div on the top of the page. Then there should be some text under the animation and if you scroll the page to the bottom there should be another smaller div with the same animation (camera) as the big div on the top of the page

Comment: You wanna have one WebGL-Element multiple on your Website in different Div-Elements, right? You just have to put your WebGL Renderer into multiple Divs. On codepen.io it's mostly the same, on each Preview-DIV is the WebGL stuff.